# How to cache a Memcached connection using the java spymemcached client

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

I am learning how to cache objects using memcached with the spymemcached client from [spymemcached examples](http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/wiki/Examples)

```
MemcachedClient c=new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("hostname", portNum));    
// Store a value (async) for one hour
c.set("someKey", 3600, someObject);
// Retrieve a value (synchronously).
Object myObject=c.get("someKey");
```

I have noted that each time I want to cache or retrieve an object I create a new memcached client which am assuming is a new connection and that memcached has no connection pooling mechanism therefore users are advised to cache the connections to decrease overhead for reconnecting from this question [opening closing and reusing connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683142/memcached-client-opening-closing-and-reusing-connections).

My question is how do I cache this connection? Can someone please give me an example I can start from. 
If you are wondering what I have tried, I tried to put my connection in the memcached but then I realized that I have to create a connection to get it. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little more research and stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598409/initializing-a-database-connection-object-once-and-reusing-it-jboss)
Then I came up with my solution as,

first created a contextlistener

```
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        Memcached.createClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

}
```

then i added the listener to the deployment discriptor by adding these lines to web.xml

```
<listener>
    <description>Used with memcached to initialize connection</description>
    <listener-class>com.qualebs.managers.ContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I created a class Memcached and added these methods

```
    static void createClient() {
        try {
            client = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 11211));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Memcached.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    static MemcachedClient getClient() throws IOException {
        return client;
    }
```

Now anywhere I need to use memcached connection just call Memcached.getClient()
I hope that will help anybody else out there with the same question.

Answer (score 2):

> I have noted that each time I want to cache or retrieve an object I
>   create a new memcached client which am assuming is a new connection

Don't do this; spymemcache uses a single connection for ALL I/O to and from memcache; it's all done asychronously; from spymemcache docs...

> Each MemcachedClient instance establishes and maintains a single
>   connection to each server in your cluster.

Just do the following ***once*** in your app; make sure the client is available to other services in your app so they can access it.

```
MemcachedClient memClient = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
```

Use `memClient` for I/O with memcache; no need to create a new instance of MemcachedClient each time; done. The link you provided answers all of your questions.

What is your deployment? web-app or standalone?

Comment: I am deploying on a web-app. I should create the connection in my servelet's init() method and then pass it to other classes, is this right?

Comment: I have solved the problem now and I am posting the answer. Thanx for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that you should use reuse the connections that you open as opposed to opening a connection for each request. It doesn't make sense to store a connection instance in memcached.

Cacheing the connection in the case means caching it in your application (keeping it in memory and open), not actually storing the connection in memcached.

Comment: But that doesn't really answer my question. `This just means that you should use reuse the connections that you open as opposed to opening a connection for each request. It doesn't make sense to store a connection instance in memcached.` you just paraphrased it.